# Getting mouse in retina coordinates

Tags: objective-c, macos

I've been using `[NSEvent mouseLocation]` to get the current location of my mouse on regular screens.  I've noticed that when I upgrade and use a Retina screen, I get the `point coordinates` rather than the `pixel coordinates`.  I understand why this is different, but I'd really like to get the mouse coordinates in `pixel coordinates`.

To do this, do I simply use the scalingFactor to translate the `mouse coordinates`.  Or is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Would appreciate any help.

## Solution

```
NSPoint location = [NSEvent mouseLocation];

for (id screen in [NSScreen screens]) {
    if (NSMouseInRect(location, [screen frame], NO)) {
        NSSize size = {1, 1};
        NSRect mouseRect = {location, size};
        NSRect retinaMouseRect = [screen convertRectToBacking:mouseRect];

        NSLog(@"Mouse Rect = %@", NSStringFromRect(mouseRect));
        NSLog(@"Retina Mouse Rect = %@", NSStringFromRect(retinaMouseRect));
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the retina cursor jumps in 1px intervals internally and not 2px/1pt intervals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over the screens in `[NSScreen screens]` to find the one where `NSMouseInRect(mouseLocation, [screen frameRect], NO)` is true. Make an `NSRect` from the mouse location point, perhaps using a size of (1, 1). Then do `[screen convertRectToBacking:rect]` to convert it to the screen's framebuffer coordinates.

Note, that's relative to that screen's origin, not the global coordinate space in which all screens are situated. The global coordinate space is in points, so there's no clear way to compute a global physical coordinate. For example, consider where the user has four screens, one on the left, two in the middle (one on top of the other), and a fourth on the right. Suppose the left display is the primary one, so the origin of the global coordinate space. Suppose the two in the middle have the same dimensions in points, but one is high-resolution and the other is not. Suppose the cursor is on the right-hand display. What should be the physical global coordinates of the right-hand display? Should it be the right edge of the primary display plus the pixel width of the top-middle display or the bottom-middle display?

Comment: Thanks that worked well!  I appreciate the follow up explanation as well.  I guess when more complicated monitor scenarios come into play, it makes sense why this would get confusing.